# Template - Wedding invitation video

Tags: video, video-editor

I am trying to create a wedding invitation video (my own wedding, Nov 2017).  I have been searching for wedding invitation video application the online, however I have not been able to find a suitable (Free) option to create a video.

I want to create something like this :
[Youtube - Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxCE8APrXSs)[image]

I have found this particular template at multiple video makers (fiverr and others) and Its perfect for what I want to create. 
Some of the other places where I found the same video 
Example : [fiverr - himaljung](https://www.fiverr.com/himaljung/create-awesome-wedding-invitation-video?context=single_query&context_type=auto&context_referrer=search_gigs&ref_ctx_id=ddada547-816a-45ac-8af7-1aeafd9abfad&filtered_price=&pckg_id=1&online=true&pos=24&funnel=2827f193-1db2-4804-be9b-23eb737b9dc6)

I am currently using Camstasia studio for editing, So I wanted to know where can I find a video template like i mentioned and which software can be used to edit it.

Comment: What is a "suitable" option for you? What makes that template perfect?

Comment: @MichaelLiebman, Free = suitable for me. Its perfect as I like the template.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Image Search I have found the exact template you were looking for:
http://aedownload.com/wedding-invitation-2533538-project-effects-videohive/

The application you need to use for it is Adobe After Effects CS4, CS5

Comment: It has page not found, dead link

Comment: The website has closed down since I have posted it, but there are others: http://effect-dl.net/wedding-album-after-effects-template-bluefx/   Use Google Image search if you want to find a similar or the same template